# Partial View not updating the razor value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a main page:

```
@model List<NovoRelatorioWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Campo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Relatorio";
}

<div id="RelatorioTablet">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        @if (Model != null)
                        {
                            <span>
                                Relatório ELO > Versão 2.0 > @Model[0].Relatorio
                            </span>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr style="border: 1px solid orangered" />

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <br />
                        <input type="button" id="butSalvar" class="form-control" style="background-color:orangered" value="Salvar" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr style="border: 1px solid orangered" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div>
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/PhonePreview.cshtml", Model)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/relatorio_elo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

}
```

and it calls another page:

```
@model List<NovoRelatorioWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Campo>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>

    <div id="PhonePreview" style="border:1px solid black;font-size:20px;">

        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <div class="container1" style="background-color:orangered;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                <div class="row" style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
                    <div class="col-sm-12" > 
                        <span style="color:white;">
                            @ViewBag.Relatorio
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            foreach (var campo in Model)
            {
                if (campo.Tipo == "Text")
                {                   
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Controles/Text.cshtml", campo)                    
                }

            }
        }
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

and it calls

```
@model NovoRelatorioWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Campo

<div class="1" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <span style="padding-left:5px;">
                @Model.Nome:
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7" style="text-align:right;">
            <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and im calling the controller via jquery ajax

```
 var urlService = "/Home/Salvar";
    var jsonobj = CriaArrayCampos();
    jsonobj = JSON.stringify(jsonobj)

    $.ajax({
        url: urlService,
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonobj,
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    });
```

It means, a page who calls a partial view, and a partial view inside. OIk, everything works, but when i click save button, i call the controller, who returns a list with objects to update the partial view (i only update the name).. But dont update.. but im making with razor... I have tested and the values comes to the partial view... how can i achieve this?

thanks so much!

Rafael

Comment: Can you show the controller action code which is getting called ? and i dont't see any form in your page, how are you posting model back to controller?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i have updated the question

Comment: If you put an `console.log` on your Json return, did you get any elements? If yes, then the problem is on your code that implements the new Objects? What are you doing when that Ajax succeed?

Comment: i think im know the error but dont know how to resolve.....because im calling the controller via ajax..The controller is called and calls the view..so i dont make nothing with the ajax return...

Comment: maybe is this why dont update the partial view...?

Comment: There are multiple errors with your code. First your input does not even have a `name` attribute so it does not post a value. And you cannot use a partial for collection items (unless you pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` so that collection indexers are added to you `name` attribute). Suggest you start by reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand how to generate you view correctly

Comment: Thanks for the answer @StephenMuecke.. I will read..but im trying to call the controller by ajax, whats is working...The view receive the parameter and works perfectly..What is not working is the partial view who not updates...When i debug, i see the new value in the razor..Just dont update in the screen....but i will read the answer..thanks again!

Comment: Nowhere in your script do you ever do anything with the response you get back from the server

Comment: Yes, i think this is my erorr...But how can i call the controller sending a javascript array (is my list of objects) and the controller calls the view and updaste the values?

Comment: @RafaelSpessotto, I dint even know what your `Salvar()` method does or returns, but your get it in the ajax success callback, and then you can do something with it, e.g. `success: function(response) { $(someElement).html(response); }` if your returning some html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke my problem is how to send the javascript object to the controller via ajax and get the return model and update the div..

Comment: The Salvar() method returns a list of my object..

Comment: I have already explained how to update the DOM in the ajax `success` callback. And as far as sending the javascript object to the client, I have no idea what your `CriaArrayCampos()` function does.